# How to replace / swap frames in Blender VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to replace / swap frames in Blender VSE?

My workflow has three stages, I generate three sets of frames for each project. Each frame folder has subfolder for each scene/shot.

- preview frames - first set of frames, low sampling 50% resolution for the client to review
- revised frames - second set with requested changes implemented, low sampling, 50% resolution, for the client's final approval
- final frames - high sampling, 100% resolution for final production

Very often, there are minor or no changes in VSE, so all I need is to have preview/review frames swapped with final frames. Deleting old frames and adding new ones is inefficient option, since I have to re-do all the effects and transitions. Is there a way to swap the frames or point Blender VSE to look for updated frames in a different folder without disrupting the VSE layout?

Comment: are your frames in a video file format (like ogg, or .mp4) or are the indivual frames pictures? (like .pgn's)

Comment: @SammySwanson PNG frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this only a day ago.  I'd changed the path where the videos were stored, and the strip after that went blank.  I pressed "N" from the VSE window, went to the right where the strip's properties showed up and clicked on the source folder, browsed for the new path, and bingo, that video came back with fading settings, keyframes etc, intact!

Hope this is all you need to do.  Just re-browse to the desired video.  If they all have the same number of frames you might get away with this.

An alternative might be to produce just the best quality video and convert/copy that to lower settings for preview etc.

Comment: This will do, thanks! The latest suggestion doesn't apply. I produce low sample, reduced preview to save costs of rendering, which builds up quickly, especially when the deadlines are tight and I need to deploy fast render farm.

Comment: I omitted to mention that you might need to press a button that pops up with some and not others - "Replace Data" or "New Data", when the filename itself is different.  I can't make it pop up at this moment!  lol